# System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<Contact> to List<Lead>

Tags: apex, visualforce

here i have created controller class to find the value using sosl query..but while am clicking the custom button am getting error..  please help me to resolve.

vfpage:

```
<apex:page controller="SoslExample">
     <apex:form >

   <apex:commandButton value="showe records using SOSL" ACtion="{!soslMethod}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="account details">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
    <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.type}"/>  
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>   
  <apex:pageBlock title="contact details">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cont}" var="c">
       <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!c.email}"/>   
    </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock> 

  <apex:pageBlock title="lead details">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lead}" var="l">
         <apex:column value="{!l.name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!l.company}"/>          
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>  

  <apex:pageBlock title="opportunity details">
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opp}" var="o">
     <apex:column value="{!o.name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!o.stagename}"/> 
   </apex:pageBlockTable>     
    </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>   
     </apex:page>
```

controller:

```
    public class SoslExample {    

         public list<opportunity> opp { get; set; }
        public list<lead> lead { get; set; }
        public list<contact> cont { get; set; }
        public list<account> acc { get; set; }

         public SoslExample ()
        {
         }

       public PageReference soslMethod() {
       opp =new list<opportunity>();
       lead =new list<lead>();
       cont =new list<contact>();
       acc =new list<account>();       
         list<list<sobject>> SearchList=[FIND 'test' IN ALL FIELDS  RETURNING     ACCOUNT (id,name,type),
                                                                             contact(name,email),
                                                                             opportunity(name,stagename),
                                                                             lead(name,company,status)];                                                                            
      acc =((list<account>)searchList[0]);
      lead =((list<lead>)searchList[1]);
      cont =((list<contact>)searchList[2]);
      opp =((list<opportunity>)searchList[3]);
      return   null ;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your result assignment as below

```
acc =((list<account>)searchList[0]);
cont =((list<contact>)searchList[1]);
opp =((list<opportunity>)searchList[2]);
lead =((list<lead>)searchList[3]);
```

Comment: thank u@highfive...but may i know the reason for error...?

Comment: You have to consider the order of the result lists coming. Have a look at the bottom section of this page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm

Comment: ok thanks...now its running.but while clicking that button nothing is displaying..i changed the string name also but still not displaying anything..

Comment: The question is about the type cast error, after resolving that if you encounter further issues try them out and post another question so that title and answers get matched. Anyway try to put some debug statements and check if there are any search results or not

Comment: yeahhh..i ll check..

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
                                                                     lead(name,company,status)];                                                                            
  acc =((list<account>)searchList[0]);
  lead =((list<lead>)searchList[1]);
  cont =((list<contact>)searchList[2]);
  opp =((list<opportunity>)searchList[3]);
  return   null ;
```

with

```
                                                                     lead(name,company,status)];                                                                            
  acc =((list<account>)searchList[0]);
  lead =((list<lead>)searchList[3]);
  cont =((list<contact>)searchList[1]);
  opp =((list<opportunity>)searchList[2]);
  return   null ;
```

Comment: thank you@patelkiran..but may i know the reason for error...?

Comment: FIND 'test' IN ALL FIELDS  RETURNING     ACCOUNT (id,name,type),
                                                                             contact(name,email),
                                                                             opportunity(name,stagename),
                                                                             lead(name,company,status)]

in query first you are getting account object (so at 0), then contact so its on 1 opportunity 3rd so should be on 2 and last lead so should be 3.